# MS Access: Unbound fields in a subform not showing on a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to fix an issue with my MS Access database report output.

**First:**
There are three forms, one of which is for navigation purposes (HOME) that has two navigation buttons in a navigation control (which link to either of the two other forms) and on subform field I use much like an iframe. There are also two reports, one for each of the other forms.

**Second:**
Both forms have unbound text fields that need to be printed onto the report output. There is no need for these fields to be saved or put into a table. *The values of these forms are printed without issue when the form is isolated* (i.e.- modal, form view, etc.). The unbound fields are part of the main body of the form where controlled fields are located.

Only when a form is viewed in the "HOME" form in the subform box/iframe does the report show `#Name?` instead of their intended values. Also worth noting, the subform does **not** have the `Link Master Fields` or `Link Child Fields` options.

The code used on the print command object/button is as follows and is located on the footer of the non-HOME forms:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    Dim strWhere As String

    If Me.NewRecord Then 'Check there is a record to print
        MsgBox "Select a record to print"
    Else
        strWhere = "[CustomerID] = " & Me.[CustomerID]
        DoCmd.OpenReport "TransferAgreement_EC", acViewPreview, , strWhere
    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? I tried searching here and Googled the issue, but I haven't quite found the solution to my problem. Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Check if you've got record/table locks in place.

Comment: Also, your report should probably better be based of a query.

Comment: The table and every field in the forms have all locks set to "no". I have not locked anything from editing. Also, I am new to Access and when looking up a method to print, the most popular method was using the above code. Only a single query is used, for pulling data from the table and filling in one of the two forms. The issue, I believe, is retrieving unbound field data into the report, caused by the fact that the forms in question are embedded in another form (HOME), used for the purpose of navigation. This is a requirement for the development of this application.

Comment: Check what the value of 'Me.[CustomerID]' is generating when it's showing the error.  I'm guessing it cant find that control.

Comment: I would think that it is looking at the unique key of the record, which in this case is an autonum digit. The record information prints, just not the unbound information. Anyway, how do I check the value of Me.[CustomerID]?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, found the solution by just running a whole lot of experiments and this fixed it.

On the report itself, on the data field needs to call to both the navigation form and the subnavigation box, then point to the unbound field. For example, one field in the control source is:

```
=[Forms]![Home]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![GCSerial_1]
```

- Home = The navigation form
- NavigationSubform = The nagivation subform box (what I consider an "iframe")
- Form = Just a call to to a form, not specific
- GCSerial_1 = The unbound text field

In this way, the report will not print the unbound fields when it is not a subform of the navigation form. For example, by default my two other forms are modal pop ups. When I "form view" them as modal prompts, the unbound fields display `#Name?` when I click my print command button, which specifies a report (no longer) contingent on a subform and not an isolated form.

THANKS FOR THE HELP AND INSPIRATION! <3